# execute Linux multiline command via PHP

Tags: php, shell, ssh

in putty i paste these lines and it works

```
cd /usr/local/vpnserver/
./vpncmd
1


Hub VPN
UserGet 34
```

but when it try to do this in php with exec or shell_exec

```
<?php

$x = exec('cd /usr/local/vpnserver/;./vpncmd;1;;;Hub VPN;UserGet 34'); 
echo $x;

?>
```

it doesn't work for me because after ./vpncmd it asks question to choose 1 2 3
I have to enter 1 and then again 2 enter and I reach my position to connect with vpn hub and can view my vpn users details.

but i can't do this in php.
**how it will work in php**

Answer (score 0):

`;` can only be used to separate commands, it doesn't work for input to the commands. If you want to supply input to a command, use a here-doc.

```
$x = exec('cd /usr/local/vpnserver/;./vpncmd <<EOF
1


Hub VPN
UserGet 34
EOF');
```

Comment: i don't know about here-doc and how it work how to use here-doc please can you explain

Comment: Make sure there's no whitespace before `EOF` on the last line. Also, I'm assuming `vpncmd` reads from standard input, not directly from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with base64_encode on the multiline parameter.