# How to execute multi line command with shell_exec?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am trying to run a multi line shell in shell_exec

```
$cmd = <<<CMD
convert  /home//test.jpg 
-font Nimbus-Sans-L -pointsize 20  \
-draw "gravity south  fill black  text 0,12 'Copyright'  fill white  text 1,11 'Copyright' " \ 
test2.jpg
CMD;
```

I tried with \ with \\ and even with \\\ and also without any !

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: perhaps check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998984/execute-linux-multiline-command-via-php) to see if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a trailing `\` backslash on the first line of the command. It should be:

```php
$cmd = <<<CMD
convert  /home//test.jpg \
-font Nimbus-Sans-L -pointsize 20  \
-draw "gravity south  fill black  text 0,12 'Copyright'  fill white  text 1,11 'Copyright' " \ 
test2.jpg
CMD;
```

---

See that this works as expected:

```php
<?php

$cmd = <<<CMD
echo abc \
def \
ghi
CMD;

print_r(shell_exec($cmd));
```

```
$ php test.php
abc def ghi
```